# Matching a key in one node with another node with list of keys

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been trying to make a graph based on a github repo and was thinking how to connect issues with labels. I've tried both as a string and as a list to no avail. Let's say an issue B has the labels with id 10,11 and 01, i would like to link it with labels with identifier 10, 11 and 01. Even when i try something as simple as :

```
match (i:issues),(l:labels)
where l.identifier in i.labels_id
create (l)-[:labels]->(i)
```

Yelds no results. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Aaand i discovered the problem. When i created the list, it was taken as a string, while the identifiers of the labels where integers. Making a conversion to string in the labels identifiers solved it:

```
match (i:issues),(l:labels)
where l.identifier in toString(i.labels_id)
create (l)-[:labels]->(i)
```

Comment: Which raises another question of mine: can i create lists that are not strings ?

Comment: Yes, but all elements in it must be the same type (so you can do a list of Strings, or a list of Ints, but not a list of Strings and Ints)